# Reliable computer for live streaming video to youtube 24/7

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, video, mini-pc

I have a live stream running that sends a 1080p video stream to Youtube. It receives the data from a camera in the network, converts the stream (using ffmpeg) and uploads it to the Youtube channel. Right now, I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 runing Raspbian Stretch Lite for this which works alright, but I did have some crash issues in the past.

(Note: These issues appeared after about a month of streaming without rebooting. I implemented an automatic reboot now which might solve this problem. It would still be nice to have a system that can run reliably for a long time without crashing.)

Does anyone have a recommendation for a small computer or microcontroller that can handle long time streaming like this? Necessary features:

- network interface (wireless or ethernet cable)
- dust proof (it is positioned beneath the floor - a fan cooling would
  probably get clogged easily)
- enough CPU/memory power for handling ffmpeg for a long time (with
  reboots every night)
- size around 15 x 15 x 10 cm (w x d x h)
- if possible, below 100 Euros

Comment: have any idea from the logs what caused the crash in the first place.  The fact that it ran for a month without issues makes it seems like it can handle the job.   I know thats not really what your asking, but if you cant make what you already have work better then thats an option as well.

Comment: yeah, I am actually asking because my department wants me to :( I added an automatic reboot now and I think it will handle it well. Still, recommendations would have been helpful.